# I get the 'Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource' for my spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am having a hard time staring up my server with spring. I looked up similar errors to mine and it seemed it had to do with the way I used RequestMapping. Despite having tried various methods to define my routes, I still can't figure out what seems to be the problem. Any ideas?

This is my error message:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'qualificationRepository' defined in com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.repositories.QualificationRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.ProgrammingLanguage.dissertation in com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.Dissertation.programmingLanguages
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'qualificationRepository' defined in com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.repositories.QualificationRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jpaMappingContext' while setting bean property 'mappingContext'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.ProgrammingLanguage.dissertation in com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.Dissertation.programmingLanguages
```

My TaskController

```
import com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.Task;
import com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.repositories.TaskRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/tasks")
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepository taskRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestBody Task task) {
        taskRepository.save(task);
        return "Successfully saved the task to the database.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Task getById(@PathVariable int id){

        Optional<Task> task = taskRepository.findById(id);

        if(!task.isPresent()){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        else {
            return task.get();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/all/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Task> getAll() {
        return taskRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

My ProgrammingLanguagesController:

```
package com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.controllers;

import com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.ProgrammingLanguage;
import com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.repositories.ProgrammingLanguageRepositories;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/programmingLanguages")
public class ProgrammingLanguageController {

    @Autowired
    private ProgrammingLanguageRepositories plRepository;

    @RequestMapping( value= "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String add(@RequestBody ProgrammingLanguage pl){
        plRepository.save(pl);
        return "This programming language has been successfully saved";
    }


    @RequestMapping( value = "/{id}/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ProgrammingLanguage getById(@PathVariable int id){
        Optional<ProgrammingLanguage> pl = plRepository.findById(id);

        if( !pl.isPresent()){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        else {
            return pl.get();
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping( value = "/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<ProgrammingLanguage> getAll(){
        return plRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Below are my entities:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ProgrammingLanguage {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    public String name;
    public String image;
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Dissertation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int qualificationId;
    public String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="dissertation")
    public Set<ProgrammingLanguage> programmingLanguages;
    public Set<Tool> tools;
}
```

```
package com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int experienceId;
    private int projectId;
    public String description;
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int experienceId;
    private int projectId;
    public String description;
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    public String name;
    public String description;
    public String client;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    public Set<ProgrammingLanguage> programmingLanguages;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    public Set<Tool> tools;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    public Set<String> images;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
    public Set<Task> tasks;
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.salay</groupId>
    <artifactId>christopher-salay-portfolio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>christopher-salay-portfolio</name>
    <description>Back-end application for my portfolio</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>8.3.1.jre14-preview</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: I think the problem is from your `ProgrammingLanguage` model. you need to also post your models

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not in your request mapping, your app does not start because of an issue in your entity mapping, please double check your mappings as stated in your error: **mappedBy reference an unknown target entity**

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.ProgrammingLanguage.dissertation in com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.Dissertation.programmingLanguages
```

It seems your class *com.salay.christophersalayportfolio.models.ProgrammingLanguage* does not have a property named **dissertation**

Otherwise, share your model to take a look!

Comment: ~@arturo.bhn is right. I encountered a similar issue before whereby it could be that your dissertation property has an @Id annotation, while it's not a primary key. Either way, please post your bidirectional association entities.

Comment: @arturo.bhn , I have updated the question with entities. The Programming language does not have a dissertation property. The intention with a lot of my models was to create multi-valued attributes. The database itself has a table called DissertationProgrammingLangues.

Comment: right, your issue lays here: @OneToMany(mappedBy="dissertation")
check out section 4 of  this short reading, that will help you to understand how the mapping works.

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-joincolumn-vs-mappedby

Cheers!